# Odd behavior with median()?

Tags: r

I'm noticing some inconsistent behavior when applying the `median()` function to dataframes.  "Inconsistent behavior" usually means that I don't understand something, so I hope someone will be willing to clear this up for me.

I realize that some functions (e.g., `min()`, `max()`) convert the dataframe into a vector and return the corresponding value for the entire df while `mean()` and `sd()` return a value for each column.  While a bit confusing, those differences in behavior don't cause many problems since most code would break if a scalar is returned instead of a vector.  However, `median()` seems to be inconsistent.  For example:

```
dat <- data.frame(x=1:100, y=2:101)
median(dat)
```

Returns a vector:`[1] 50.5 51.5`

But, sometimes it breaks:

```
dat2 <- data.frame(x=1:100, y=rnorm(100))
median(dat2)
```

Returns: `[1] NA NA
Warning messages:
1: In mean.default(X[[1L]], ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
2: In mean.default(X[[2L]], ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA`

However, `median(dat2$x)` and `median(dat2$y)` both yield the correct result.

Also consider the following:

```
dat3 <- data.frame(x=1:100, y=1:100)
dat4 <- data.frame(x=1:100, y=100:199)
```

In the above, `median(dat3)` returns `[1] 50.5   NA`  while `median(dat4)` returns `[1]  50.5 149.5`!  I would expect both or neither of these to work.  So, I clearly am not understanding just how the `median()` function is working.

Further, functions like `sd`, `mean()`, `min()` and `max()` all yield their expected (if seemingly inconsistent) results in all of the above cases.

I know that I can use something like `sapply(dat2, median)` to get the necessary result, but am wondering why the R gods chose to implement these core stats functions in a way that, at least on the surface, seems inconsistent.  I suspect that I, and probably other neophytes, are probably not understanding some fundamental concept, and I'd appreciate your insight.

Comment: I wish I had read R Inferno a bit more closely.  I just went back and looked, and the author states: "The example of median with data frames is a troublesome one ... there is not a data frame method of median. In this particular case it gets the correct answer, but that is an accident. In other cases you get bizarre answers." (p.54).  I'm now motivated to give R Inferno a good, solid read this weekend.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This exact phenomenon was recently discussed in the [median and data frames](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2011-April/060731.html) thread on R-devel.  The consensus seemed to be that the `mean.data.frame` method should be deprecated and users should rely on `sapply`.

Comment: Perfect, thank you!  I'm a bit embarrassed for not having found that thread.  It's clear that `mean` and `sd` are the inconsistent functions, not `median` (although I still think it is inconsistent in other ways).  In hindsight, it is odd to expect a function that usually aggregates a vector of numbers to work on a dataframe at all.  A better question would have asked why mean.data.frame was implemented in the first place.

Answer (score 6):

`median` hasn't got a metod for `data.frame` class objects, unlike `mean`. Use `plyr` package and `colwise` function to achieve desired result. Or use `*apply` function family.

```
> sapply(mtcars, median)                                                                                                     
    mpg     cyl    disp      hp    drat      wt    qsec      vs      am    gear                                              
 19.200   6.000 196.300 123.000   3.695   3.325  17.710   0.000   0.000   4.000                                              
   carb                                                                                                                      
  2.000                                                                                                                      
> colwise(median)(mtcars)                                                                                                    
   mpg cyl  disp  hp  drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb                                                                       
1 19.2   6 196.3 123 3.695 3.325 17.71  0  0    4    2
```

Comment: Thanks aL3xa.  It has been my habit to use sapply.  I'm still a bit new to R and am still sometimes disturbed that functions don't specify argument types and throw an error if something inappropriate is passed to them.  It sounds like the best habit is to always use sapply or colwise when a column-by-column result is desired.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is with the package `miscTools`

```
> library(miscTools)
> dat3 <- data.frame(x=-50:50, y=(-50:50)^2)
> colMedians(dat3)
  x   y 
  0 625
```

which is correct, unlike

```
> median(dat3)
[1]   0 850
```

The package `matrixStats` also has a `colMedians` function, but not for dataframes.

Comment: Thanks @Henry.  I didn't know about miscTools; it looks like there are a few good linear algebra tools in there.